# how to import files into python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on Learn python the hard way and am not a very experienced programmer and I have searched on Stackoverflow and other programming websites but I have not found the answer to my question. Well anyway my question is how do you import files into another file in python what I have seen is that many people have answered this by saying that you should just put `import filename` but when I do this I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source.py", line 1, in <module>
    import one
ImportError: No module named filename` so how do I import a file without getting this error. if anybody would like to know where to go to see why I'm asking question go to http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex45.html. I'm also using a chromebook so I have an app named source lair instead of the traditional python software, so if anybody has a chromebook or chromeos computer please give me suggestions as to if this is a good app and if there's a better app. ps: you can download the app from the chrome store on any operating system.

```
print "thanks"
```

Comment: Do you have a script named `filename.py` in the same directory as `script.py`?

Comment: Instead of literally `filename`, if your file is saved as something other than "filename" you need to use the actual filename.  For example, if your file is called "game.py" you should use `import game`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python looks for modules in `sys.path`.
in python

> > import sys
> >
> > print sys.path          ... it will print the list of directories where it look for modules

you can add a directory in sys.path

> > sys.append("name_of_directory")

or you can set PYTHONPATH environment variable for directory.

Comment: that should be `sys.path.append("name_of_directory")`

Answer (score 2):

just put the file "filename.py" into the same dir as source.py if you sure you have created a file named "filename.py". Then `import filename` in source.py will work.